# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'message') at SafeSubscriber._next (notifications-query.component.ts:56:21)

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I get the above error while I am getting some Data from api. This error if the data is null, if the api returns some data then this error is not coming.

I am using the below piece of code and subscribing the service.

```
this.systemMessageService.getSystemMessage().
        subscribe(res => {
            if (res.message !== null && res.message !== undefined) {
                this.systemMessage = res.message;
            } else {
                this.systemMessage = undefined;
            }
        });
```

Please help me how I can handle this error

Comment: replace `if (res.message !== null && res.message !== undefined)` with `if (res?.message)`. The issue is that the "res" variable can be null/undefined and this change will resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You should add also res to your if statement, e. g. if (res && res.mesage) or in shorter way if (res?.message){...} else {...}

Answer (score 0):

You're immediately trying to access the property `message` of the `res` variable without checking if `res` is defined. I'd propose to change the condition to one of the following

#### Option 1: double-bang operator `!!` + ternary operator `?:`

```js
this.systemMessage = (!!res && !!res.message) ? res.message : undefined;
```

The `message` property will only be accessed if `res` is defined.

About double-bang operator from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784946/6513921): *"Converts `Object` to `boolean`. If it was falsey (e.g. `0`, `null`, `undefined`, etc.), it will be `false`, otherwise, `true`"*.

We could also use the [ternary operator `?:`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to simplify the if-else to a single statement.

#### Option 2: optional chaining operator `?.`

```js
this.systemMessage = res?.message;
```

Essentially the same as option #1, but using the [optional chaining operator `?.`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining). Again, the `message` property will only be accessed if `res` is defined.

Importantly, from the docs, *"instead of causing an error if a reference is `nullish` (`null` or `undefined`), the expression short-circuits with a return value of `undefined`"*. So you could skip explicitly assigning the `undefined`.

#### Option 3: Nullish coalescing operator `??`

```js
this.systemMessage = res.message ?? undefined;
```

The [nullish coalescing operator `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) returns the value of LHS (`res.message`) if it's defined or the value of RHS (`undefined` in your case) if it's LHS is nullish.